# Increasing Node Allocatable Memory on an EKS Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

Occasionally my EKS nodes become NotReady and freeze-up due to high page swapping. This occurs despite the fact that swapping is disabled, likely due to the [explanation here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53533#issuecomment-427233471) on why swapping can't actually be disabled on Linux.

To remediate this, I'd like to increase the amount of memory that is reserved by the node (and unavailable for pods). I have observed issues with swapping only above 95% memory utilization, so by restricting the node to 90% usage I should be able to prevent swapping induced by memory pressure.

1. What is the correct way on EKS to customize Node Allocatable for a managed node group?
2. Do I need to create a new node group or can I update an existing one?
3. Must the node group be created with eksctl or can I customize a node group created in the AWS web console too?

Comment: Did you see pods been evicted when your node is under pressure?

Comment: @gohm'c no, I don't

Comment: You should see pods been evicted first. Do you currently use self-managed node group with custom image?

Comment: No, it's all AWS managed node groups.

Comment: There are pods without memory limits though. (I know this is a problem, but it's not entirely under my control.)

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? When node is `NotReady`, could you please run `kubectl describe node {node-name}` and check `Events:` (at the bottom of the command output) and paste it here?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor no, afraid not. We've added memory limits and it hasn't occured since, but I'd still like to customize Node Allocatable

Comment: Could you answer my questions - which Kubernetes version are you using? When node is NotReady, could you please run `kubectl describe node {node-name}` and check `Events` (at the bottom of the command output) and paste it here?

Comment: @MikolajS. yes, will check and follow up later this week